# Does deleting a record from Kafka state store deletes the record from changelog topic as well?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, aggregation, tombstone

We have a Kafka stream aggregation topology. We need to keep the size of the changeLog topic in check to reduce the Kafka storage costs. So we use transformer (DSL API) in the topology to schedule a punctuation that deletes the old records from the stateStore using keyValueStore.delete().
I am able to verify that after a delete, on further scheduled triggers of the punctuation, the deleted key is not there in the state store. But does it remove the record from the changeLog topic as well? More importantly, does it reduce the size of the changeLog topic as well so that the Kafka storage cost is in check??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, changes to the state store are applied to the changelog topic.

Comment: Thanks. And will it reduce the storage size of the changeLog topic or will it just mark the record as 'soft delete' such that the storage of the changeLog topic is still unaffected?

Comment: All changelog topics are compacted and hence eventually the deletes (which go as tombstones) will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no actual record deletion into the `changelog` topic when you issue a "delete" command. Be aware that a "delete" command is in fact a record with a `null` value (aka `tombstone`) written into a topic (`changelog` or any other) - see [here](https://kafka.apache.org/26/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#streams_concepts_ktable):

> null values are interpreted in a special way: a record with a null
> value represents a "DELETE" or tombstone for the record's key

So, in fact the interpretation is the one that makes it feel like a deletion; one could read a `changelog` topic (you'll have to know the exact topic's name) as a KStream or by using the Kafka Consumer API and will find the `tombstone` records there (till removed by the compaction or retention thread). But if you read a `changelog` or any compacted topic with a KTable than a `tombstone` record will determine a deletion from the associated store - you'll no longer find the related key in the store despite the fact that it actually exists in the related compacted topic.

If compaction policy is enabled on a topic (by default is enabled on `changelog` topics) than its records are removed till the last one for a specific key. So at some point you'll only have the delete record because the previous records with the same key are removed by the compaction Kafka thread.

Comment: Thanks. So the tombstone is written into the changelog topic as well. I would need to delete the tombstone records as well to save on the Kafka storage size. I found this property [delete.retention.ms](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#delete.retention.ms) which i set to 1 day while the retention.ms config is set to 7 days. I set the cleanup.policy to [compact, delete]. In my local env. I do not see the records getting deleted. Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, we have the retention.ms config as 7 days due to a business requirement (an event can be updated till 7 days). But in 7 days we get a lot of messages resulting in huge Kafka Storage costs. So that's why we have started deleting the processed records immediately by sending a tombstone message.